# Testing the controller of a comment that belongs to a post in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I'm very new to Rails and my knowledge of Ruby is pretty rusty as well. Anyway, I'm trying to write my first Rails app the right way with good test coverage. I've been trying to follow the [getting started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide and combining that with the [testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) guide to accomplish this. (why were these two things not combined!?)

So, now I'm stuck at trying to test adding a method to the `Comments` controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

This is as far as I got with my test:

```
class CommentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase  
  setup do
    @comment = comments(:one)
  end
  test "should create comment" do
    assert_difference('Comment.count') do
      post :create, comment: { body: @comment.body, commenter: @comment.commenter, ???? }
    end

    assert_redirected_to post_path(assigns(:post)) #???? 
  end
end
```

with this fixture

```
one:
  commenter: mystring
  body: mytext
  post: 

two:
  commenter: mystring
  body: mytext
  post:
```

My problem is I don't see how to create and reference a Post to be the parent of the comment in an idiomatic Rails way.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a parameter `post_id` to the create request (this `post_id` is used by the line `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])` in the controller). Example:

```
class CommentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase  

  setup do
    @comment = comments(:one)
    @post = posts(:post_one)
  end

  test "should create comment" do
    assert_difference('Comment.count') do
      post :create, comment: { body: @comment.body, commenter: @comment.commenter }, post_id: @post.id
    end    
    assert_redirected_to post_path(assigns(:post))
  end

end
```

This code assumes you have defined a `Post` identified by `:post_one` in your fixtures.